# Animação no Floating Action Button

Tags: android, animação

Alguém sabe como fazer a animação do Floating Action Button exibida no vídeo abaixo?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oVKQfCZ3z2g&feature=youtu.be

Eu descompilei o apk desse app e pude ver que essa animação não é feita com resources, mas via código (talvez seja possível, mas essa não é feita assim).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aqui está a resposta:

**scale_fab_in.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="500"
    android:fromXScale="0"
    android:fromYScale="0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="1"
    android:toYScale="1"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/overshoot"/>
```

**scale_fab_out.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="400"
    android:fromXScale="1"
    android:fromYScale="1"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="0"
    android:toYScale="0"
    android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/overshoot"/>
```

A partir daqui:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27922191/floating-action-button-animation/27922318#27922318